# Container div is expanding to 100% in IE and I don't want it to expand

Tags: css

I need the container to expand based upon the information input in it, but in IE it automatically expands to 100% because there is no width set on the container, but setting a width on the container would limit the information allowed inside and shift the containing information. The container is absolutely positioned and the divs inside are floating.

The tooltip is a dropdown that works when the user mouses over the #top_panel. Both the top_panel and tooltip need to expand based upon the information placed inside them, so there is no width set on them.

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    right:33px;
    top:15px;
}

#top_panel {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    height:31px;
    background:url(../main_bg.gif) repeat-x top left;
    border: 1px solid #6a6a6a;
}

ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
}

#panel_info {
    visibility:visible;
    margin-left:18px;
    list-style:none outside none;
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
}

#panel_info li {
    border-right: 1px solid #a9a9aa;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

#tooltip {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#f8f0ce;
    border-left:1px solid #6a6a6a;
    border-right:1px solid #6a6a6a;
    border-bottom:1px solid #6a6a6a;
}

#tooltip li {
    display:block;
    padding:4px;
}

#logout {
    width:82px;
    height:31px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    margin-left:-9px;
    margin-top:10px;
    clear:right;

}

#logout ul {
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}


<div id="container">
    <div id="top_panel">
        <span onmouseover="$('div#container').addClass('hover');" onMouseOut="$('div#container').removeClass('hover');">
            <ul id="panel_info">
                <li>Name
                    <div id="panel_arrow">
                    </div><!-- end panel_arrow -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="type">Development
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span><!-- end mouseover event -->
        <div id="logout">
            <div id="logoutIcon">
            </div><!-- end logoutIcon -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end logout -->
    </div><!-- end top_panel -->
    <div id="tooltip">
        <ul>
            <li>You are now lodded in DEV</li>
            <li><strong>Company:</strong>This is the company</li>
            <li><strong>Company ID:</strong> This is the company ID</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end tooltip -->
```

Comment: Here is a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/evRXB/) for those who want to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE at the 'puter I'm at right now so I'm not too sure how IE will handle it, but try the "white-space" style on your menu elements.
"white-space: nowrap;" for instance will stop the browser from breaking line at space.